# Add currenttime label on video iOS

Tags: ios, video, swift3, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm having a problem with adding a label that displays the current time on the video, but I do not know where to start
Right now, I have two options
1, record video through didOutputSampleBuffer, AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
2. Record video, then edit the video eg https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ReaderWriter/Introduction/Intro.html.

I chose option 2 and manually added AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor, but the app crashed (guessed by the wrong PresentationTime when append adapter)

What I want to know is how can I paint onto a timeline similar to a video? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mmrBDA1baY